# How do I upload a date field from csv into TestRail

Tags: testrail

I am a bit disgusted to get stuck on this, but I am.
I have Test Rail, and I have a csv file, from which I import test cases. A line in the csv file would something like this

```
blah,06/01/2020,blah,blah
```

The Date field isn't liked

```
A date value does not match the specified date format (column 2: "06/01/2021")
```

Date format shown in TestRail's importer is

```
MM/dd/yyyy
```

I just don't get what's wrong. I mean, don't my formats match up? Well I guess they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out the answer eventually. It was to do with the input file format, an excellent source for little quirks.
Having tried two values for the File Encoding field

1. Windows-1252(Latin) Excel Default
2. UTF-8

For which the Date was not validated, I checked in notepad++ for the actual file encoding. There is an Encoding option in the top level window menu list there. From that I switched to using

```
UCS-2LE
```

From that point, everything worked.
The motto of the story then seems to be that TestRail has a lot of options in the File Encoding dropdown menu because it needs to have a lot of options - it's not forgiving.